# jQuery find when the inside left edge of an element meets the right outside edge of an element within it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, not really sure about this one exactly. But I want to know is it possible when I have one element inside of another and I animate the inner element to move left so that it moves out of the outer elements view (overflow is hidden). I want to trigger something when the far edge of the inner element reaches the inner edge of the outer element. Hope this makes some sort of sense.

Just don't know how to approach it, so don't know where to start looking.

Comment: I combination of the various height/width/position functions on [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/) page should get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly but jQuery.animate() gives you the option to specify a callback function on completion. [Like this](http://jsfiddle.net/twbz2/2/).